# iPhone Cannot Access Spring Boot API

Tags: node.js, iphone, spring, spring-boot, cors

I am working on a fullstack app that uses Spring Boot as its backend.  I am able to deploy it online, but I would like to be able to test the UI on my iPhone locally.  I am using my local IP Address "xxx.xx.x.xx" to access it.

The frontend works fine, but it cannot make requests to the backend.  When I try to access the backend port, the connection times out.

.

**What I Have Tried**

I have tried using Safari and Google Chrome on my iPhone.  And I have tried my iPad.

I have tried making requests from the frontend, and also going directly to the API port url.

I have tried using a test Spring Boot app without any dependencies and it still doesn't work.

I have tried configuring Cors, but I have had no luck.

I am able to make API requests on when I deploy it online.

I am able to access the backend API port via my iPhone, if I deploy a node server.

.

**Testing Code**

https://github.com/metalwing1212/test-spring-boot-server

https://github.com/metalwing1212/test-node-js-server

I have tried testing small servers, and even I still cannot connect to "http://xxx.xx.x.xx:8080/test" on my iPhone to the Spring server.  But I can connect to "http://xxx.xx.x.xx:8082/test" from my iPhone to the Node server.  And I can connect to "http://xxx.xx.x.xx:8080/test" on my Laptop to the Spring server too.

My Spring Boot Controller code is as follows.

```
package com.test.test;

import java.time.Instant;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

// @CrossOrigin
@RestController
public class TestController {
    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String test() {
        return "Spring: \"" + Instant.now().toEpochMilli() + "\"";
    }
}
```

When I try to connecting to the Spring server from my iPhone, it times out.

.

**Does Anyone Why This Might Be?**

Does anyone know why this might be, and can I do about it?